# Image to be loaded into pdf file created from Sharepoint Server Images Folder

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, itext

I am using ItextSharp Library to generate pdf files on a button click on my SharePoint Site. I want to use a logo on the pdf whose image resides on the Images Folder of Sharepoint. I am unable to do that.

Can someone help me with it.

Below is the code that I am using which is getting the instance from window32 which I dont want.

```
 protected void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Font Arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, BaseColor.GREEN);
      Font Verdana = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 16, Font.BOLDITALIC, new BaseColor(125, 88, 15));
      string imagepath = SPContext.Current.Web + "/_layouts/Images/Image1.png";
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
          using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,15,15))
          {
              PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms); 
              document.Open();
              Paragraph img = new Paragraph();
              Image jpg = Image.GetInstance(imagepath); --- Getting an error here stating "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\CustomSystem\_layouts\Images\Image1.png'"
              img.Add(jpg );
          }
       }
      }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with SharePoint development but you're problem is with this line:

```
string imagepath = SPContext.Current.Web + "/_layouts/Images/Image1.png";
```

This string must be an absolute path path such as `c:\www\sites\image.png`, not a relative one which it is right now. I can tell its relative because when you ask ASP.Net to get something for you but you don't specify a path it looks in `%WINDOWS%`.

I don't know how you're using `SPContext.Current.Web` but according to the docs calling `.ToString()` on it returns the title of the website which is what would happen if you concatenated it with a string like you are. My guess is that you don't need that but could be wrong.

If the `layouts` folder is a subfolder of the folder that the file you are working on is in then you should be able to use `Server.MapPath` to get the absolute path:

```
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("_layouts/Images/Image1.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it work by making use of  string imagepath = Page.Server.MapPath("/_layouts/Images/ImageFolder/Image1.gif" ) ;

Answer (score 0):

i have done like this in my sharepoint site

```
string url = "http://fspl-dsktp-038:8000/Style%20Library/FSPL/CorporateLogo.png";

//iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("images") + "//images/FSPL LOGO.png");

iTextSharp.text.Image logo =iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(url); 
logo.ScaleAbsolute(90, 90);
Imagecell.AddElement(logo);
gvTable.AddCell(Imagecell);
```